# How to get deepest object in associative array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get deepest object in associated array like below.

```
interface Tree {
    id: string
    name: string
    child?: Tree[]
}
const treeArray: Tree[] = [
    {
        id: "test", name: "test1", child: [
            { id: "Test#2", name: "@2ndtest" },
            {
                id: "test#2", name: "2ndtest", child: [
                    { id: "Test#2#3", name: "@3rdtestTestTest" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "testtest", name: "testtest2", child: [
            { id: "TestTest#2", name: "@2ndtesttest" }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: "testtesttest", name: "testtesttest3"
    }
]
```

In above "treeArray", I want to get deepest object like `{ id: "Test#2#3", name: "@3rdtestTestTest" }`.

So, I tried to use recursion function like below.

```
const deepestObject = (arr: Tree[]) => {
    let arrayDeep = 0
    let arrayNumber:any = []
    arr.forEach((e,i) => {
        if (e.child) {
            arrayDeep += 1
            deepestObject(e.child)
        }
        if(arr[i].id === e.id){
            arrayNumber.push(arrayDeep)
        }
    });
    return arrayNumber
}
console.log(deepestObject(treeArray))
```

I was expected this code out put was [2,1,0] but [1,2,2] was output.
If I get array like [2,1,0] in my code ran, I would select largest number in array and then I pick up object and recursive function again.
Actually I really confused how should I simple way to get deepest object in my case.
Does anyone advise me, please?

Comment: What is `[2, 1, 0]` supposed to signify? You expect first element -> second element -> first element which seems like `[0, 1, 0]` to me. Not sure what `2` is supposed to be. Unless you're counting *backwards* and `test1` is the third element from the end? I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just want to get deepest object from treeAray in my code. Actually, I don't what to do first time. that's why my function is really wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find the deepest path, fetch the object there:

You can try to recursively find the deepest path in the object first and then simply fetch the item at the end of it. To this end, an internal `helper()` function will walk the Tree objects and their children and find the deepest nested item. The result is an array of indexes to fetch from the tree structure, e.g., `[0, 1, 0]`:  first child (index zero) -> second child (index 1) -> first child (index zero).

TypeScript implementation:

```typescript
const deepestObject = (arr: Tree[]) => {
    if (arr.length === 0)
        return null;
    
    function helper(el: Tree | Tree[], runningDepth: number[], deepest: number[]): number[] {
        //if array - apply recursively on each element. return only the deepest of all
        if (Array.isArray(el)) {
            return el.reduce(
                (lastDeepest, item, index) => helper(
                    item,                       //item
                    runningDepth.concat(index), //append to the running depth path
                    lastDeepest                 //pass the deepest we know of
                ), 
                deepest
            );
        }
        //terminal condition  - it's a Tree element and has no `.child` property
        if (!el.child) {
            //if the running total depth is greater, return that
            if (runningDepth.length > deepest.length)
                return runningDepth
            else //or just return the last one
                return deepest;
        }

        //recursively apply...
        return helper(
            el.child,     //...to all children...
            runningDepth, //...pass the current path to append to...
            deepest       //...and the current deepest path
        );
    }

    const path = helper(arr, [], []);
    const lastIndex = path.pop();
    const parentArray = path.reduce((lastArr, nextIndex) => {
        return lastArr[nextIndex].child!; //override the compiler check:
                                          //we found this path, so it must exist
    }, arr);
    return parentArray[lastIndex!]; //override the compiler check:
                                    //only case where lastIndex will be undefined is if
                                    //the input is an empty array which is handled in the beginning
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQig3gWAFDKHLAAmAXMgM5hSgDm+RyIcAthBdbSAwUQgAtgAGxIB+CukwBtALr4AvvgQB7ENWQ1MAQShQ4AT0kYIc5AF5k0xkVx8mhUhQBEkas4A0zNh2SuI1ACMnsiCIuRWNg4OWMQRzqgBYADEAEwhLOwuAAKpICRuYM7ICh5R0bblFQ5OfoVpGT4ueQVJIWGiFNb21b2xtQlJackAzI1ZftkjUK3UiXNtJWU9vUTyKxWlVWvlWz121QOFheO+-tSF6V4dEd2rhP3x82DPDV6ZZ7n5x4t71etMP6VDaOeI-C5td5NOpJcFgMa7fCyADc+GUag0JEwAAckgB5ABGACsIAgwBZkAAKOB6YwyWQASgsAD5kAciMAYFSaVAAHTCCA8MACCzmSwABgZ20IGDAAFcoCBmHLhMJUT1yjA5SAycA1MgBBBhLioJSjXSUAAfNAmOReKDakD0AAiEGxwooIDlrAJ0DtyCxbqSnu9vqgcgZIZ9ftkbOlyAA9AnOcgeYZkABaVPY7HCAzIDAIBWUYAANyN+f1EEQIqNEHY4F5BYg8sVyDUec0hoDOKS7a5cFV8ZTlN0+gMvOAlDHhjNwgZTPZq1lCqVRt5GBIcqQlPj1Upwjg1FdQeoXmAkFY5-yEAAHkzzKzDcboLuQfdHJevB-VkmL-W93uB0QCdHhXXdAReVUHU4DASlQCxe8vCTOAc0FEhNBULsUGA0C6B7CDkGxWCBEA1ZD2PXsNB-Igk2IyhKGwntT3JAB3FAAGsQBUVj+zIhwGS8fimEDXFqH4hl1WqJR3yTSAoFYUBB1CNQSAvPUlUzYgwAAckYuAbUwZA6wbck4HyA0j2YLCAAMoKEUQbKIqAVBNMADGHLlKQAQnXG5F34v8uWFHDHXoTCwGUrFCKnZA6AwWDoHtFtVy7WD+JHXCXTdYV+UFOhhWQVlRKSPKhQEKV32qFc2yysCctIqqiCNSgUCTFQoGQIk5Q0GqlRC5AKPJNQIGEog+uYsSwCkzY0VkhNC2LMsK2zXMJ15Xl4wm58TTfD8-Ickhv1ohMNt5MAsMHYRQkOjAQDO-i6rocDhWQ06NvoxiBqLPRBXJYjCou1b0Mwh6msIErqIcJMzvMjDvoVO7yUh-6SPjSTETwcpoI0AGRUsHbXx5Lx-QjGbCBx8khoASRvW8KTx3lsVcykMZ6SmiJpP6Z3zSxGc3bcIEpA8jzAMd3jvMBacQh9WSXBwJqGsdpBASXpbvWR7PCbzkUTBMVHLPRSBQb6VFYbERGgG7SQ4sgxpomik3Y5AYBUbV4aERi8a8SgsIvZBWB68k7ynMBdi8Hk2aYCbiKRnnpBpunvJRPWDegWgsSY1RzctzrBBtu3wYd399ZATsECPFBWMNDBBtF9X6dYkRrt9ZB3YgGBQAgDDYs5e3i+hhMBtAbE5XJWLzOM833NTPR02r4BBGIRiBDhgUe-67tfToUA8MUOacZUAV+RUOhKRRwkSTJSktAgHmFyAA)

JavaScript demo:

```js
const deepestObject = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0)
    return null;

  function helper(el, runningDepth, deepest) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      return el.reduce((lastDeepest, item, index) =>
        helper(item, runningDepth.concat(index), lastDeepest),
        deepest
      );
    }

    if (!el.child) {
      if (runningDepth.length > deepest.length)
        return runningDepth
      else
        return deepest;
    }

    return helper(el.child, runningDepth, deepest);
  }

  const path = helper(arr, [], []);
  const lastIndex = path.pop();
  const parentArray = path.reduce((lastArr, nextIndex) => lastArr[nextIndex].child, arr);
  return parentArray[lastIndex];
}

const treeArray = [ { id: "test", name: "test1", child: [ { id: "Test#2", name: "@2ndtest" }, { id: "test#2", name: "2ndtest", child: [ { id: "Test#2#3", name: "@3rdtestTestTest" }, ] }, ] }, { id: "testtest", name: "testtest2", child: [ { id: "TestTest#2", name: "@2ndtesttest" }, ] }, { id: "testtesttest", name: "testtesttest3" } ];

console.log(deepestObject(treeArray));
```

### Directly return the deepest item

Similar idea as the above. However, instead of finding the path to the item, `helper` returns the item itself. It also needs to keep track of the depth it was found at, so it takes and returns an object with both a depth counter and the object found at that depth.

TypeScript implementation:

```typescript
const deepestObject = (arr: Tree[]) => {
    if (arr.length === 0)
        return null;

    function helper(el: Tree | Tree[], runningDepth: number, max: {depth: number, obj: Tree | null}): {depth: number, obj: Tree | null} {
        //if array - apply recursively on each element. return only the deepest of all
        if (Array.isArray(el)) {
            return el.reduce(
                ({depth, obj}, item) => helper(
                    item,            //item
                    runningDepth +1, //increase the running depth
                    {depth, obj}     //pass the deepest we know of
                ), 
                max
            );
        }
        //terminal condition  - it's a Tree element and has no `.child` property
        if (!el.child) {
            //if the running total depth is greater, return new object
            if (runningDepth > max.depth)
                return {depth: runningDepth, obj: el};
            else //or just return the last one
                return max;
        }

        //recursively apply...
        return helper(
            el.child,       //...to all children...
            runningDepth,   //...starting at the the current depth
            max
        );
    }
    
    const result = helper(arr, 0, {depth: 0, obj: null });
    return result.obj;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=62&ssc=2&pln=27&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpQig3gWAFDKHLAAmAXMgM5hSgDm+RyIcAthBdbSAwUQgAtgAGxIB+CukwBtALr4AvvgQB7ENWQ1MAQShQ4AT0kYIc5AF5k0xkVx8mhUhQBEkas4A0zNh2SuI1ACMnsiCIuRWNg4OWMQRzqgBYADEAEwhLOwuAAKpICRuYM7ICh5R0bblFQ5OfoVpGT4ueQVJIWGiFNb21b2xtQlJackAzI1ZftkjUK3UiXNtJWU9vUTyKxWlVWvlWz121QOFheO+-tSF6V4dEd2rhP3x82DPDV6ZZ7n5x4t71etMP6VDaOeI-C5td5NOpJcFgMa7fCyADc+GUag0JEwAAckgB5ABGACsIAgwBZkAAKOB6YwyWQASgsAD5kAciMAYFSaVAAHTCCA8MACCzmSwABgZ20IGDAAFcoCBmHLhMJUXhyjA5SAycA1MgBBBhLioJSjXSUAAfNAmOReKDakD0AAiEGxwooIDlrAJ0C8rDgAA8KFgse6BJ7vb6oF4VMSLchrV7VQoGSGwx7lT6-cg40SE0mVcIFGzpcgAPTlznIHmGZAAWhr2OxwgMyAwCAVlGAADcjW39RBECKjRB2OBee2IPLFbmQK3NIbkFi3Ulc1y4Kqy9XKbp9AZecBKHvDGbhAymezVrKFUqjbyMCQ5UhKWXqpTQ27hbHiaViJBWCZcxWUNY1oFfEF7kcACvHuStgAAt97gdEAnR4V1w2QABqQIvHgnUMDgSgUGFFAULQuhly-AQkNWT9wx-IkSyYStsSIyhFxQFdcQ0AB3FAAGsQBUXj11ohwGS8cSmADQNxIZdVqiUSDK0gKBWFATdQjUEgEL1JUG3-AByDi4BtTBkFHcdyTgfIDSI5gVGQAADXkbmc5BsSgFQTTAAxty5SkAEJ7xuS9xPgrlSPbR16E0FQwC0jMRSPZA6EItT7WnW9mAgUS81JMBxJ3ciXWo5BWVk3lkqlSDqhvWd6MzUr0OoxiKCNBRFPuI1iIrcsVCgZAiTlDQGqVaLhCI8k1AgaSiHG5BZO66JlLLSsOy7Xt+ybFsD15Xky0W0CTQgqDQqEURYIcSsDt5MAnM3YRQkukgMBAO7xJaugMO-IhboO6gaTAOK4HJaLos7PRBXJZLxNkssFMRHpylUdRyQwSgVXJSwTvAnkvHFLwmojZAidzeNlVVEokZ6RbMex3k83VNa8DRygVAFfkVDoSluPxYlCspLQIBPAwLyAA)

JavaScript demo:

```js
const deepestObject = (arr) => {
  if (arr.length === 0)
      return null;

  function helper(el, runningDepth, max) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) {
      return el.reduce(
        ({depth, obj}, item) => helper(item, runningDepth + 1, {depth, obj}), 
        max
      );
    }

    if (!el.child) {
      if (runningDepth > max.depth)
        return {depth: runningDepth, obj: el};
      else 
        return max;
    }

    return helper(el.child, runningDepth, max);
  }

  const result = helper(arr, 0, {depth: 0, obj: null });
  return result.obj;
}

const treeArray = [ { id: "test", name: "test1", child: [ { id: "Test#2", name: "@2ndtest" }, { id: "test#2", name: "2ndtest", child: [ { id: "Test#2#3", name: "@3rdtestTestTest" }, ] }, ] }, { id: "testtest", name: "testtest2", child: [ { id: "TestTest#2", name: "@2ndtesttest" }, ] }, { id: "testtesttest", name: "testtesttest3" } ];

console.log(deepestObject(treeArray))
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for your both answers! I tried to understand your answers and your comment is helpful to understand logic for me. I really want to write that kind of code some day! Thank you so so much! I really really appreciate it. I keep trying to understand recursive function. It is difficult for me. Thank you for your help!!